# Improve Performance of Geoprocessing Service - GPServerSync.Load

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, printing, performance, geoprocessing-service

I have a geoprocessing service in ArcGIS Server 10.1 that is a simple Print Task.  The task is running as an Asynchronous service.  It renders one MapService from the same ArcGIS Server instance, and another basemap mapservice from ArcGIS online and generates a PDF.  The service is taking over 3 minutes to run.  When I turn verbose logging on, I notice that the elapsed time between the following log messages is around 3 minutes:

```
<Msg time='2014-06-16T06:11:55,546' type='VERBOSE' code='20023' target='WebPrinter.GPServer' methodName='GPServerSync.Load.PrintTask' machine='AGDC-DEV4.LOCAL' process='9632' thread='10020' user='null' elapsed='0.00084'>Load job jc01d9192a4bb4eecbc8317b3d12b34d9 message type REST message size 1218</Msg>
<Msg time='2014-06-16T06:14:13,724' type='VERBOSE' code='103004' target='WebPrinter.GPServer' methodName='Map.Draw' machine='DEV4.LOCAL' process='9632' thread='10020' user='null' >Beginning of geography phase.</Msg>
```

Once the draw phase starts, the job finishes in seconds.  I am unclear on what the GPServerSync.Load method does, and how to optimize it.  If I try making a PDF in ArcMap of the two same services, it takes seconds.  I do not think that the services involved in making the map are the holdup.

**EDIT**
Upon digging further, the culprit is in this following line of arcpy:

```
result = arcpy.mapping.ConvertWebMapToMapDocument(Web_Map_as_JSON, templateMxd)
```

The method ConvertWebMapToMapDocument is taking 2+ minutes to complete.  Now, I feel like this issue is related to the issue [Why is arcpy.mapping.ConvertWebMapToMapDocument slow?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83826/why-is-arcpy-mapping-convertwebmaptomapdocument-slow)

Thoughts?

Comment: I am having the same problem with the print GP. the problem is it works way faster with all other formats i.e. PNG, JPG, BMP etc, But when i try to print to PDF, it still works but takes 2-3 mins.